# How to change label in ViewController when app enters the foreground

Tags: iphone, xcode4, viewcontroller, foreground, background-foreground

i want to change a label in my view controller when the app enters the foreground....:

SalaryAppV4AppDelegate.h

```
@interface SalaryAppV4AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {

//----------------------------------------------    

    NSTimeInterval appEnteredBackground;

    NSTimeInterval appEnteredForeground;

    NSTimeInterval difference;

    NSString *times;

//-----------------------------------------------
```

SalaryAppV4AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

{


    //perform -(IBAction)DoThis

    FirstViewController* controller = [FirstViewController alloc];
    [controller DoThis]; 




    //releasing
    [dateFormatter release];





}
```

FirstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction) DoThis
{

    appDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];

    //This Doesn't Work :(
    label.text = @"IT Has Worked";


    //This Works
    NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.times);

}
//--------------------------------------------------------
```

i just want the label.text ti change to anything but nothing in the viewcontroller changes...

Comment: Is your "label" object marked as an IBOUTLET in FirstViewController.h?  Also, is it properly rigged up in Interface Builder (assuming you're using a NIB?)

Comment: yep = IBOutlet UILabel *label; and it is hooked up to the files owner so confused.... i must be missing something so simple....

Comment: Do you still have this problem?

Comment: It's just that you seem to have replied positively to one of the answers. As such duplicating isn't the right approach to gain attention and disapproved on the site.

Comment: dont understand what you are saying.. im new to this and not as clever as you and just need some help

Comment: Please, **stop asking** the same question repeatedly. If you need to change something in your question, you can simply edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Is label hooked up in Interface Builder?

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger that "label" is not nil?

Comment: Noob question... how do I do that :)

Comment: Run the app in debug configuration in the simulator.  You're probably already doing this.  Place a breakpoint at "label.text".  Place cursor over "label" and see what the address is.  You can also open the console (command-r) and type 'po label'.

Comment: it just says... UILabel * label 0x0

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that label is not nil. Second if your viewcontroller is in a navigation stack then you need to get your view Controller from navigation stack.

Here is a code snippet to get viewController from Navigation stack

```
HomeViewController *vController = nil;
    NSArray *vControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    for(UIViewController *v in vControllers) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[HomeViewController class]]) {
            vController = (HomeViewController*)v;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RootViewController * controller = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
```

-(IBAction) DoThis
{

```
appDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];
```

change this to like with setText:

```
[label setText:@"IPhone/Ipad Chat Room"];
//This Works
NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.times);
```

}

Comment: pleas let me know while u complete

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `applicationWillEnterForeground:` method, you are creating a new instance of FirstViewController and then calling your method `DoThis:` on it, which does change the label text. However, this controller is not a member object and the version of it that you see that does not update is probably in another code file somewhere - or is it in your app delegate too?

In short, although you do change the text it's not the correct object which is why you do not see any visible change, I reckon.

Comment: the label is in my firstViewController.xib and the -(void)DoThis is in  firstViewController.m but i want the void to be performed when the app returns to the foreground.... i'm so lost :/

Answer (score 0):

Using the method in the App delegate and a instance call to the View Controller

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
   [ViewController.label setText:@"DA TEXT"]; //if the VC is a property.
   [[ViewController instance].label setText:@"DA TEXT"]; //if is not a property

}
```

If is not a property, you must set an instance class method at your VC