# How to change label in ViewController when app enters the foreground

Tags: iphone, label, viewcontroller, foreground, background-foreground

i want to change a label in my view controller when the app enters the foreground....:

SalaryAppV4AppDelegate.h

@interface SalaryAppV4AppDelegate : NSObject  {

//----------------------------------------------

```
NSTimeInterval appEnteredBackground;

NSTimeInterval appEnteredForeground;

NSTimeInterval difference;

NSString *times;
```

//-----------------------------------------------

SalaryAppV4AppDelegate.m

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

{

```
//perform -(IBAction)DoThis

FirstViewController* controller = [FirstViewController alloc];
[controller DoThis]; 




//releasing
[dateFormatter release];
```

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------

FirstViewController.h

import UIKit/UIKit.h>
import "SalaryAppV4AppDelegate.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

```
IBOutlet UITextField *text1;
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
IBOutlet UILabel *labeltotal;
IBOutlet UILabel *differenceLabel;


int i;
float number1;
NSTimer *timer;

SalaryAppV4AppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

}

//Actions

-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;

-(IBAction) beginTimer;

-(void) DoThis;

//Properties

@end

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

FirstViewController.m

-(IBAction) DoThis
{

```
appDelegate = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] retain];

//This Doesn't Work :(
label.text = @"IT Has Worked";


//This Works
NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.times);
```

}

//--------------------------------------------------------

i just want the label.text ti change to anything but nothing in the viewcontroller changes...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change label in ViewController when app enters the foreground](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268094/how-to-change-label-in-viewcontroller-when-app-enters-the-foreground)